# Where did this Rebel Alliance/Jedi Order emblem originally appear?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, star-wars-rebels, the-rebel-alliance

Where, if anywhere, did this mixed emblem of the Rebel Alliance and Jedi Order originally appear...?

[image]

Comment: The only place I found it is for people attempting to sell it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This original work is by an artist named [boosh2001](https://www.deviantart.com/boosh2001/art/Rebel-Alliance-Jedi-Order-Insignia-310400931).

> A tattoo design merging the Rebel Alliance and Jedi Order Insignia
>
> Fairly rudimentary attempt inspired by image I discovered here [[link](https://www.newschoolers.com/photos/view/483364/Rebel-Alliance)]
>
> Always loved both insignia and whilst I had always considered getting a tattoo of one or the other at some point, I couldn't decide which I liked better. This seems to be the best of both worlds.
>
> As I said, it's fairly rudimentary at the moment, but I will try and tidy it up and repost at some point in the future.
>
> <sub><sup>https://www.deviantart.com/boosh2001/art/Rebel-Alliance-Jedi-Order-Insignia-310400931</sup></sub>

Designing Star Wars emblem tattoos seems to be something of a hobby of his.

[image] [image]
[image] [image]